# SQL - Get matches where match is NULL or parameter with one-to-many

Tags: sql-server-2008

Table Rule:

```
RuleID    RuleName
1         Rule1
2         Rule2
3         Rule3
4         Rule4
```

Table Equipment:

```
EquipmentID     EquipmentName     EquipmentCode
1               Equip1            E1
2               Equip2            E2
3               Equip3            E3
```

Table RuleEquipment:

```
EquipmentRuleID   RuleID    EquipmentID
1                 1         1
2                 1         2
3                 2         1
4                 2         3
5                 3         2
```

A user will query using one and only one EquipmentCode.  I want to return the Rules which either have no associated Equipment or have the matching equipment.

So, if a user queries for E1, the result set should be

```
RuleID    RuleName
1         Rule1
2         Rule2
4         Rule4
```

I cannot put my finger on the WHERE clause for this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Rule 
WHERE Rule.ID NOT IN (SELECT RuleID FROM RuleEquipment)
OR Rule.ID IN 
(
   SELECT RuleID 
   FROM RuleEquipment 
      INNER JOIN Equipment ON RuleEquipment.EquipmentID = Equipment.EquipmentID
   WHERE Equipment.EquipmentCode = @inputEquipmentCode
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from [Rule] as R
where R.RuleID in (select RE.RuleID
                   from RuleEquipment as RE
                     inner join Equipment as E
                       on RE.EquipmentID = E.EquipmentID
                   where E.EquipmentCode = 'E1') or
      R.RuleID not in (select RE.RuleID
                       from RuleEquipment as RE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Rule.*
FROM Rule
LEFT OUTER JOIN RuleEquipment ON RuleEquipment.RuleID = Rule.RuleID
Where Rule.RuleID = 1 or RuleID IS NULL
```